# JavaScript Canvas drawImage deforms my image

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, stretch, drawimage

No matter what I try, I can't figure out why does drawImage vertically stretch a picture. Here is the code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="padding:0;border:0;margin:0 auto;
width:320px;height:456px;z-index:0;"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var d = new Image
d.src = './images/portadilla.jpg';
d.onload = function a(){context.drawImage(d, 0, 0);}
</script>
```

My image is 456px high and 320px wide, same as the canvas. I've tried using different images and formats, but the problem remains. How would you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're not setting the size of the canvas correctly. Don't use CSS/style to set the size but use its attributes:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=456 style="..."></canvas>
```

Your image is stretched because the default size of the *bitmap* for a canvas element is 300x150 pixels so if you don't set the size properly the canvas *bitmap* will be stretched to fit the *element* size set with CSS.

You can also set the size using JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 456;
```